# For loop with 2 if statements - Error: Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am writing a "for loop" in r Programming With 2 if conditions in a row (not a Chain, one "if" is separate and subsequent to the first "if").

I run this loop on a "test" vector (numeric vector). This "test" variable can go above the value of "Limit" (numeric vector). However, if, at time [i], "test" goes back down below "Limit", this is interpreted as a "remakepoint", and "Limit" is increased by 5 at time [i+1].

This is my code:

```
testLimit<-function(test){
Limit<-vector()
remake<-vector()
remakepoint<-vector()
Limit[1]<-test[1]
remakepoint[1]<-0
for(i in 2:length(test)){
  Limit[i]=Limit[i-1]
  if(test[i]<=Limit[i]){
    remake[i]<-0
  } else {
    remake[i]<-1
  }
  remakepoint[i]=remake[i]-remake[i-1]
  if(remakepoint[i]==-1){
    Limit[i+1]=Limit[i]+5
  } else {
    Limit[i+1]=Limit[i]
  }    
}
return(data.frame(test,Limit,remake,remakepoint))    
}
```

However, it Returns the following error:

```
Error in if (remakepoint[i] == -1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I don't understand why it doesn't get the remakepoint[i]==-1, this has just been calculated in the row above: remakepoint[i]=remake[i]-remake[i-1]

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

you never gave `remake` a value at 1, so the first `remakepoint[i]=remake[i]-remake[i-1]` call gives an `NA`:

```
remakepoint[2]=remake[2]-remake[1]
```

to fix it, try setting:

```
remake <- c(0)
```

instead of:

```
remake<-vector()
```

EDIT: There are several other errors in the code, maybe include a desired input and output for trouble shooting purposes.

You also have an error if your last value is larger than the limit - it sets the next limit, and breaks as the limit column has more rows than the rest. You can fix this by trimming the end off in the return function:

```
return(data.frame(test,Limit[1:length(test)],remake,remakepoint))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy - you were of great help. If you have time, please let me know what the "several other errors are". However, Your help was highly appreciated, thanks again! :)